# Creating an infinite table in Hive (avro)

Tags: hive, cloudera, avro

I am new to Hive and Cloudera. I am trying to create a table in Hive from avro schema and then load data there. The code for table creation is below:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE newTab3
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.literal'='{
    "namespace": "namespaceNameTochange",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "customer",
    "fields":  [
    { "name": "name","type": "string"},
    { "name": "id","type": "int"}
    ]
}');
```

Table is created successfully (the columns are as in avro schema). However, number of rows grows infinitely, and all of the values are null, even before loading data into the table. 
Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you are facing this problem? before insertion or after insertion ?

Comment: @Bector just straight after creation of the table before loading or inserting any data